# How is an NPN relay switch circuit analysed?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, relay

So I came across this good article: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html

It gave me a good insight into the different transistor-relay switching circuits. But unfortunately, it hasn't provided any detail regarding the analysis of such circuits, more specifically the NPN relay switching circuit. 
[image]

Above is an image from the article, of an NPN relay switch circuit.

The only way I can think of working through the circuit is by modeling it as shown below and then analysing it:

[image]

I haven't analysed such a circuit before and would love to know what the general approach is.

Comment: Are you just trying to understand the snubber or do you not understand how the transistor is being used? Please edit your question to make it clear exactly what you are asking so we don't waste time explaining what you already know.

Comment: @Transistor I understand how transistors function here. However, I do not know how to analyse NPN relay switch circuits. The drawing I provided is how I reckon the analysis gets done. But I am not sure if thats the correct way.

Comment: When the Vin is at high state the BJT's is in saturation (full-on) and the collector is shorted together with the emitter. Hence the relay coil will see full supply voltage across his terminals and energize the relay contacts.

Comment: The diode really has nothing to do with the transistor, but to counter the relay inductance when the relay switches off.  And the relay is just a fancy resistor.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat so do I short out the diode when I am analysing the circuit?

Comment: When transistor is on, is diode forward or reverse biased?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, when the transistor is "on" the diode will be reverse biased, so you can ignore it. A high voltage is applied at the base, this pulls the collector low as it allows current through the relay coil. Current through the relay coil activates the relay.

When the transistor shuts off is when the diode comes into play. The transistor base is switched from high to low. This cuts off current into the collector. But the current through the inductive coil can't change instantaneously. Reducing its current only happens when a reverse voltage is applied to it. So cutting off the BJT's collector current actually leads to the collector node voltage going above the supply rail. This puts the diode into forward bias, giving the coil current somewhere to go. The coil current drops due to the voltage applied counter to the direction of current. Once the current drops near zero, there is essentially no forward bias on the diode and it shuts off, leaving both ends of the coil at the same voltage.