# Regulated input relay switch

Tags: relay, comparator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ZrIM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The control input may vary. What I want is, the relay will only switched on if the input voltage on R1 is at least 5 V. It works but the relay produce "buzzing sound" (like in the middle of switched OFF to  ON but not enough voltage).
Do I need more than this simple schematic ? Any suggestion would be appreciated, including op-amp voltage comparator example very welcome.

Comment: What relay are you using?

Comment: Just an ordinary 5 pins general purpose 12V relay.  [like this](https://www.makerlab-electronics.com/product/5-pin-mini-spdt-relay-12v-10a-250v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple circuit that will do what you are asking for. There should be a 100nF bypass capacitor on the 12V supply as well. Input voltage can be -0.3V to +12V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2eVXx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The op-amp is used as a comparator in this case. R1 and D1 form a +5V reference voltage. R3 and R2 provide a bit of hysteresis so the relay snaps on or off without chattering even if the input voltage is changing slowly.

You can replace R1 + D1 (5.1V zener diode) with 2K & 1.5K resistors respectively if the 12V supply is clean and well-regulated.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your circuit:

1. If you want a well-controlled and accurate turn-on threshold for your relay, you should probably use a comparator at the input to be sure the switching happens at the voltage you want it to happen at. There are other possibilities, but a comparator is the most straightforward and foolproof one.
2. If you want to switch on a 12 V relay, you need to apply pretty near 12 V to the coil. 10 V or 11 V might work (the minimum "must operate" voltage will be specified in the relay datasheet if you are buying from a reputable manufacturer). But your circuit is only applying 4.3 V or so, and that's not going to work well at all.

   If you want to use an NPN BJT to buffer the output of a comparator to drive a relay, you'll most likely want to connect that BJT as a *low-side* switch between the relay coil and ground, for example as shown in [this prior question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455837/).

Answer (score 1):

what you've done is build an emitter follower, with 5V on the input that circuit will only send about 4.4 volts to the relay, not enough to switch it reliably, the rest of the voltage in the supply goes into heating up the transistor,

Instead you could use the common emitter circuit below. here 3-5V on the input will turn the relay on and less than 0.5V will turn it off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuApdO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>